# What's an OSX command line tool or simple app to remove extended ASCII characters from source text files?

Tags: ascii, extended-ascii

I've been cutting and pasting some code snippets from an Amazon Kindle eBook into a text editor (JetBrains PhpStorm), and apparently each time it comes with some extended (>127) ASCII characters.

Is there simple cmd line sed/awk/tr command, or a simple OSX App to strip them out?

Comment: Why is this considered off topic?  http://stackoverflow.com/faq says questions may include "software tools commonly used by programmers".  The question also adresses "a specific programming problem".  Extended ASCII characters cause parsing problems in many IDEs/editors, diff/merge tools, and compilers/interpreters/browsers.  This is a very real and specific problem+solution that affects programmers of all types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [this blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix), here is a solution that worked well for me:

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < infile > outfile
```

Note that if you get this error: **tr: Illegal byte sequence**, this can be solved by setting LANG=C via:

```
export LANG=C
```

(not sure why setting LANG=C helps, but that's what others with the same problem were doing)

Answer (score -1):

[Plain Clip](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/plain-clip/) has always been my go-to OS X app for stripping out unwanted characters/whitespace/etc.